# Got an error when uploading image in Wordpress in mime_content_type()

Tags: php, html, wordpress, stack, mime

I was uploading an image in my dashboard then a sudden fatal error came:

This is the error log:

```
[15-Jun-2020 16:06:15 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function TUTOR\mime_content_type() in /home/danoc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/tutor/classes/User.php:54
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/danoc/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(289): TUTOR\User->profile_update(1)
    #1 /home/danoc/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
    #2 /home/danoc/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
    #3 /home/danoc/public_html/wp-includes/user.php(1876): do_action('profile_update', 1, Object(WP_User))
    #4 /home/danoc/public_html/wp-includes/user.php(1995): wp_insert_user(Array)
    #5 /home/danoc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/tutor/classes/Student.php(135): wp_update_user(Array)
    #6 /home/danoc/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): TUTOR\Student->update_profile('')
    #7 /home/danoc/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
    #8 /home/danoc/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
    #9 /home/w in /home/danoc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/tutor/classes/User.php on line 54
```

Please help to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I would disable all plugins and upload the image, then try and activate them one by one, and keep uploading images each time till you find your disruptive plugin.

---

At least that will tell you if it's a plugin related issue.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Hello @Zakaria El Khachia, its still the same.

Comment: I tried to change the theme too but that also gives the same outcome.